# Python Requests: auth + custom header

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying to get the following curl command to work in Python 2.7:

```
curl --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.korra-preview" --user [username]:[password] https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg/outside_collaborators?per_page=100\&page=1
```

(basically just gets a list of collaborators from a GitHub organization)
This is utilising the GitHub API v3 - https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/outside_collaborators/

I've read through the Requests library documentation and can't figure out how to pass BOTH authorisation and custom headers. Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the code I've written so far. How do I include both the auth and varHeaders in the get request?

```
import requests

varUsername = raw_input("GitHub username:\n")
varPassword = raw_input("GitHub password:\n")

varHeaders = {'Accept':'application/vnd.github.korra-preview'}

#req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user/repos',auth=(varUsername,varPassword))
req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg/outside_collaborators?per_page=100\&page=1',auth=(varUsername,varPassword))
print req.status_code
print req.headers
print req.encoding
print req.text
print req.json()
```

Comment: just use the `headers` argument

Comment: Dope! Knew it was going to be stupidly simple.
For anyone else who runs into this, add another parameter headers=headers:

`req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg/outside_collaborators?per_page=100\&page=1',auth=(varUsername,varPassword),headers=varHeaders)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a third parameter, in the form 'headers=varHeaders'

```
req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/orgs/myorg/outside_coll‌​aborators?per_page=1‌​00\&page=1',auth=(va‌​rUsername,varPasswor‌​d),headers=varHeader‌​s)
```

Thanks Brendan for pointing this out!